# How to get Android current location "only on demand" using Location Manager but without Location Listener?

Tags: android, location

My app does not need on-the-fly location updates. It needs the location only when (1)The app starts; (2)A specific activity/fragment is opened; (3)The user hits "get my location" button.

The criteria is: when demanded the location must come fast even if it is coarse with (if possible) minimum battery consumption. I plan to use a method along the lines of:

```
public void getLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

        if(location != null) {
            //save the location to shared prefs to use when needed
            return;
        }

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(location != null) {
            //save the location to shared prefs to use when needed
            return;
        }

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(location != null) {
            //save the location to shared prefs to use when needed
            return;
        }

        // if reached that point the location cannot be got!!
    }
```

The plan is to call that method every-time the app starts, or a specific page is activated, or user wants to get the current location. Unless those actions trigger a location update, the old location or no location is enough. Does this approach make sense? Can I do that without implementing Location Listener and/or calling the method "requestLocationUpdates()"? My concern is "getLastKnownLocation()" may not give the current location when called since I am not sure how often or at what conditions that "last known location" from a provider is updated.

Any suggestions and comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: storing the location in Shared Prefs and retrieving them when necessary seems to be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Use the Following Code to get the Current and Last Known Location using Google Location Services API

```
//Global Variable
Location location;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

   @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}

  @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

AnyActivity.class

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
Location location = main.location;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Your code seems like listening to the location updates continuously. I do not prefer that. There are multiple fragments and activities. I need a global method that I can call whenever I need to get the location from any activity or fragment in the app. Unless I call the method, no updates are necessary.

Comment: run this code when the app runs for the first time, then store it in Shared Prefs. Make a global variable to store the Location and you can request that variable from any activity or fragment you need

Comment: That makes sense. The location is only updated if the main activity is opened. What if the user changes her/his location without closing the app or opening the main activity? Say the user is in a bus/train and starts the app (with main activity) and gets the location then switches to another activity and while this new activity is open the vehicle travels 20 miles. At that point the location is updated but we still have the old one. If the user switches to a third page that he will need current location, he still have the old one. So do we need to put listener to all the activities?

Comment: That`s very good! I will certainly consider it. I wonder, though, what is wrong with my approach of doing all that without a listener since I don`t need location update unless user takes an action?

Comment: I will give you up-vote for your good suggestion but your answer does not answer my original question. May be some one else would give another solution.

Comment: Implementing all garbage all together and using "This" everywhere is the worst way of coding.